# NetBeans JIRA Module does not seem to cope with customised workflows

Tags: netbeans, jira

I've spent about a day on Google trying to find an answer to this, but to no avail.

Our instance of JIRA has a customised workflow for our project and we would like to use the NetBeans JIRA module to transition issues to the next step in our workflow ("Testing") when our developers commit a change.

However, the JIRA module in NetBeans does not offer any transitions in either the Commit dialog or the Edit Issue window.

We've tried a vanilla JIRA instance with the default workflow and that works fine, but we want a more detailed workflow for our project.

I can't even find an author or even source for this module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got around to downloading the entire NetBeans source and picked through the JIRA plugin code.

The workflow **IS** hard-wired to the standard default JIRA workflow.

However, after consultation with the author of the plug-in, we have come up with a way to make the plug-in compatible with any workflow.

Hopefully an update to the plug-in will be available from the 7.3 beta version of NetBeans.